# Replacing duplicates within a row with NA keeping the first in R in the row

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate data rowwise. For e.g.

```
> head(data_Final)
  ID   Value1    Value2  Value3   Value4
1 a      876      989      989      758
2 b      921      801      971      995
3 c      636      889      7724      95
4 d      999      999      896      999
5 e      251      254      251      235
6 f      552      100      669      015
```

I need the results like:

```
> head(data_Final)
  ID   Value1    Value2  Value3   Value4
1 a      876      989      NA      758
2 b      921      801      971     995
3 c      636      889      7724    95
4 d      999      NA       896     NA
5 e      251      254      NA      235
6 f      552      100      669     015
```

I searched a lot but the results were for duplicates in a column not in a row.

Comment: You could pivot the data to long form, group by ID, mutate the duplicate values, and then pivot back to wide form.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` to loop over the numeric columns, and `replace` the `duplicated` elements with `NA`

```
data_Final[-1] <- t(apply(data_Final[-1], 1,
       function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
data_Final
#  ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#1  a    876    989     NA    758
#2  b    921    801    971    995
#3  c    636    889   7724     95
#4  d    999     NA    896     NA
#5  e    251    254     NA    235
#6  f    552    100    669     15
```

---

The `apply` can be changed to `for` loop as well

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data_Final))) {
   tmp <- data_Final[i, -1]
   data_Final[i, -1] <- replace(tmp, duplicated(tmp), NA)
  }
```

---

Or using `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data_Final %>%
     select(-ID) %>%
     pmap_dfr(., ~ c(...) %>%
            replace(., duplicated(.), NA)) %>%
     bind_cols(select(data_Final, ID), .)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time(t(apply(data_Final[-1], 1,
       function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.013   0.003   0.015 


system.time(for(i in seq_len(nrow(data_Final))) {
        tmp <- data_Final[i, -1]
        data_Final[i, -1] <- replace(tmp, duplicated(tmp), NA)
       }
 )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.014   0.004   0.018
```

Regarding the discussion of `for` vs `apply`, it is already documented in multiple posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533246/why-is-apply-method-slower-than-a-for-loop-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933130/apply-vs-for-loop-in-r) and there is not much difference

#### data

```
data_Final <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
     Value1 = c(876L, 
921L, 636L, 999L, 251L, 552L), Value2 = c(989L, 801L, 889L, 999L, 
254L, 100L), Value3 = c(989L, 971L, 7724L, 896L, 251L, 669L), 
    Value4 = c(758L, 995L, 95L, 999L, 235L, 15L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Well, never seen you use apply for quite a while now

Comment: @Onyambu with row wise, it is easier to express and get the calculation instead of pivoting/repivot etc. I like the elegance of for loop, but it is just subjective

Comment: @akrun Yes, I also found for-loop more readable often. And sometimes really "faster" Because when using `apply` on data frames, often one has to use `t()` and `data.frame()` to be able to do it. But as I said, sometimes with `apply()` the computer became very slow. It was appreading when df was really huge. Maybe because one changes in-situ the values ...

Answer (score 2):

```
replace.dup <- function(x, val=NA) {
    x[duplicated(x)] <- val
    x
}


replace.row.wise.dups <- function(df, val=NA) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      df[i, ] <- replace.dup(unlist(df[i, , drop=T]), val)
    }
    df
}
```

In this case I would just use `for`-loop.
`(l)apply` and `t()` can bend your mind quite easily ...
`for` is not THAT slow. Sometimes `apply` functions are very slow.

#### recreate `df`

```
text <- "  ID   Value1    Value2  Value3   Value4
1 a      876      989      989      758
2 b      921      801      971      995
3 c      636      889      7724      95
4 d      999      999      896      999
5 e      251      254      251      235
6 f      552      100      669      015"

txt <- gsub("\ +", "\t", text)

df <- read.delim(text = txt, sep="\t", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

#### run it

```
replace.row.wise.dups(df, NA)

#   ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
# 1  a    876    989   <NA>    758
# 2  b    921    801    971    995
# 3  c    636    889   7724     95
# 4  d    999   <NA>    896   <NA>
# 5  e    251    254   <NA>    235
# 6  f    552    100    669     15
```

#### `for`-loop slightly slower than `apply`

Sorry I was wrong. I thougth `for`-loop is faster. But in case your df is very large, `for`-loop might give you more speed. Probably because of memory issues, as @akrun pointed out.

```
# from @akrun
replace.row.wise.dup.1 <- function(df, val=NA) {
  as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))))
}

require(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark("apply" = replace.row.wise.dups.1(df, NA),
                      "for-loop" = replace.row.wise.dups(df, NA),
                      times = 1000)
# > mbm
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#     apply 600.950 623.9905 673.0897 632.4485 645.910 3668.063  1000
#  for-loop 696.792 727.8785 791.7684 754.1875 772.129 2491.147  1000
```

Comment: @akrun yes, that I had from you. (I had instead assignments). But it is about the for-loop in this case. `apply` functions for such stuff at data frames can become very slow.

Comment: @akrun - I told you, my answer is not about `replace()`. It is about to apply `for`-loop. In R, there is a myth that `apply` functions are faster and more efficient thatn the `for`-loop. But it is simply not true.

Comment: @akrun I will change my functiion because you are making the point with `reaplace()`.

Comment: @akrun not true, my function doesn't change in-place the `df` outside.

Comment: @akrun I don't care. My point was just `for`-loop vs. `apply()` and all its consequences `t()` and `data.frame()` ...

Comment: @akrun you are right, I did some mistake in benchmark. Took wrong function.

Comment: You could compile the `for` loop and make it a bit more faster, but any case it is pointless to do comparison with apply and that was my take.  Reason i commented strongly is to give correct info and nothng else. thanks

Comment: @akrun Thanks! I thought `for`-loop in this case is faster. Sometimes one has to do `t()` with `data.frame()` because of apply. I wanted to prove myself just out of curiosity. Sorry, didn't want to annoy you.

Comment: I find the `t` to be very fast though, i could be wrong.  Only issue may be the memory for large datasets

Comment: @akrun Ah that might be true that it is the memory footprint ... sometimes apply-functions were taking more than 30 min to process a huge data frame. That is true ... could be because of memory ... (I am in bioinformatics and we have sometimes several hundreds Mb or even several Gb sized tables)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `ave`:

```
data_Final[-1]<-ave(unlist(data_Final[-1]), row(data_Final[-1]),
                    FUN = function(x)`is.na<-`(x,duplicated(x)))
data_Final
  ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
1  a    876    989     NA    758
2  b    921    801    971    995
3  c    636    889   7724     95
4  d    999     NA    896     NA
5  e    251    254     NA    235
6  f    552    100    669     15
```

Comment: interesting to use ``is.na<-`` directly