# How do I apply multiple functions to each list item while accessing and dynamically updating a non-list object?

Tags: r, list, function, apply

I have an initial `value` as well as three datasets in a list:

```
  value <- 10
  df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), quantity = c(3, 7, -2))
  df2 <- data.frame(id = c("d", "e", "f"), quantity = c(0, -3, 9))
  df3 <- data.frame(id = c("g", "h", "i"), quantity = c(-2, 0, 4))
  df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I would like to apply multiple functions to each data frame in the list, dynamically update the `value` at the end of the operations, and then run the same procedure on the next list item. The challenge is that the functions themselves take `value` as an input.

Here is how I would accomplish this without using the apply function:

```
  # Example function 1: Generate `outcome` by multiplying quantity times a random number
  df_list[[1]]$outcome <- df_list[[1]]$quantity * sample(1:10, 1)

  # Example function 2: Multiply `value` by `quantity` to update `outcome` 
  df_list[[1]]$outcome <- value * df_list[[1]]$quantity
  
  # Updates `value` by adding the old `value` to the sum of the outcome column:
  value <- value + as.numeric(colSums(df_list[[1]]["outcome"]))

  # Repeats operations for df_list[[2]] and df_list[[3]]
  df_list[[2]]$outcome <- df_list[[2]]$quantity * sample(1:10, 1)
  df_list[[2]]$outcome <- value * df_list[[2]]$quantity
  value <- value + as.numeric(colSums(df_list[[2]]["outcome"]))
  
  df_list[[3]]$outcome <- df_list[[3]]$quantity * sample(1:10, 1)
  df_list[[3]]$outcome <- value * df_list[[3]]$quantity
  value <- value + as.numeric(colSums(df_list[[3]]["outcome"]))
```

I can use lapply to run the functions on each list item, but how do I access (and dynamically update) the non-list object `value` before proceeding to the next list item?

Comment: Isn't this `df_list[[1]]$outcome <- value * df_list[[1]]$quantity` and 

  
  `df_list[[1]]$outcome <- df_list[[1]]$quantity * sample(1:10, 1)`completely replaceing the 'outcome' i.e. if the second step is done without considering the value of outcome, why the first step was assigned

Comment: Yes—good point. Both functions are examples, not the actual (more complex) functions I'm interested in, and the random number product was the first thing I thought of, although of course you're right that it makes the first function pointless. I've edited to reverse the order of the functions (which I admit only marginally makes them more meaningful) and noted that they are examples only.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case the `for` loop in the solution is the easiest and flexible one compared to a `Reduce` based approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we need to update, use a `for` loop i.e loop over the sequence of `list` and change the index

```
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
     # Multiplies `value` by `quantity` to obtain `outcome` for each row in df_list[[1]]
       df_list[[i]]$outcome <- value * df_list[[i]]$quantity

       # Updates `outcome` by multiplying by a random number
       df_list[[i]]$outcome <- df_list[[i]]$quantity * sample(1:10, 1)
       value <- value + as.numeric(colSums(df_list[[i]]["outcome"]))
       }
```

-output

```
> value
[1] 84
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this with `lapply`? I'm wondering if accessing and updating non-list objects is possible inside `lapply`.

Comment: @hoho You may use `<<-` for updating the value in global, but it is still not a good option.  Another way is with `Reduce`, but when you have multiple objects going into the function, it is not that flexible and have difficulty in understanding

Comment: @hoho  you may also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933130/apply-vs-for-loop-in-r) about the difference in iterative vs independent evaluation